# Pricing header in css

Tags: css

I will wish to obtain this result below

[image]

I am stuck on the pricing header. In fact, I don't understand why does not the color pink take up all the space?

[image]

I think that my problem is my padding and margin on my price-item?

```
.price .price-item {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto 30px auto;
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .07);
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/*******************************/
/********** Price CSS **********/
/*******************************/

.price {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.price .section-header {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}


.price .container {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 40px auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}


.price .price-item {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto 30px auto;
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .07);
}

.price .price-header {
  padding: 30px;
  background: #F7CAC9;
  color: #343148;
}

.price .price-status span {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  right: -30px;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #343148;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 14px;
  background: #F7CAC9;
}

.price .price-title h2 {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.price .price-prices h2 {
  font-size: 45px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.price .price-prices h2 small {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-top: 9px;
  margin-left: -12px;
}

.price .price-prices h2 span {
  margin-left: 1px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<!-- Price Start -->
<div class="price">
  <div class="section-header">
     <p>Yoga Package</p>
     <h2>Yoga Pricing Plan</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="price-item">
       <div class="price-header">
       <div class="price-title">
          <h2>Basic</h2>
       </div>
       <div class="price-prices">
           <h2><small>$</small>49<span>/ mo</span></h2>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="price-body">
         <div class="price-description">
             <ul>
                <li>Personal Trainer</li>
                 <li>Special Class</li>
                 <li>Free Tutorials</li>
                 <li>Group Training</li>
             </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="price-footer">
         <div class="price-action">
             <a class="btn" href="">Join Now</a>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>

            <div class="price-item">
              <div class="price-header">
                <div class="price-title">
                    <h2>Basic</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="price-prices">
                    <h2><small>$</small>49<span>/ mo</span></h2>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="price-body">
                <div class="price-description">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Personal Trainer</li>
                        <li>Special Class</li>
                        <li>Free Tutorials</li>
                        <li>Group Training</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="price-footer">
                  <div class="price-action">
                    <a class="btn" href="">Join Now</a>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="price-item">
              <div class="price-header">
                <div class="price-title">
                    <h2>Basic</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="price-prices">
                    <h2><small>$</small>49<span>/ mo</span></h2>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="price-body">
                <div class="price-description">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Personal Trainer</li>
                        <li>Special Class</li>
                        <li>Free Tutorials</li>
                        <li>Group Training</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="price-footer">
                  <div class="price-action">
                    <a class="btn" href="">Join Now</a>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div> 
        </div>
```

Comment: because the parent element `.price-item` has a `padding` which will not allow the child element `.price-header` to become bigger

Answer (score 0):

You did not override the default heading style of H2 which has some margin by default on simply do below

```
h2{margin:0}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
h2{margin:0}

/*******************************/
/********** Price CSS **********/
/*******************************/

.price {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.price .section-header {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}


.price .container {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 40px auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}


.price .price-item {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto 30px auto;
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .07);
}

.price .price-header {
  padding: 30px;
  background: #F7CAC9;
  color: #343148;
}

.price .price-status span {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  right: -30px;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #343148;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 14px;
  background: #F7CAC9;
}

.price .price-title h2 {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.price .price-prices h2 {
  font-size: 45px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.price .price-prices h2 small {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-top: 9px;
  margin-left: -12px;
}

.price .price-prices h2 span {
  margin-left: 1px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<!-- Price Start -->
<div class="price">
  <div class="section-header">
     <p>Yoga Package</p>
     <h2>Yoga Pricing Plan</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="price-item">
       <div class="price-header">
       <div class="price-title">
          <h2>Basic</h2>
       </div>
       <div class="price-prices">
           <h2><small>$</small>49<span>/ mo</span></h2>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="price-body">
         <div class="price-description">
             <ul>
                <li>Personal Trainer</li>
                 <li>Special Class</li>
                 <li>Free Tutorials</li>
                 <li>Group Training</li>
             </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="price-footer">
         <div class="price-action">
             <a class="btn" href="">Join Now</a>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>

            <div class="price-item">
              <div class="price-header">
                <div class="price-title">
                    <h2>Basic</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="price-prices">
                    <h2><small>$</small>49<span>/ mo</span></h2>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="price-body">
                <div class="price-description">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Personal Trainer</li>
                        <li>Special Class</li>
                        <li>Free Tutorials</li>
                        <li>Group Training</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="price-footer">
                  <div class="price-action">
                    <a class="btn" href="">Join Now</a>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="price-item">
              <div class="price-header">
                <div class="price-title">
                    <h2>Basic</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="price-prices">
                    <h2><small>$</small>49<span>/ mo</span></h2>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="price-body">
                <div class="price-description">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Personal Trainer</li>
                        <li>Special Class</li>
                        <li>Free Tutorials</li>
                        <li>Group Training</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="price-footer">
                  <div class="price-action">
                    <a class="btn" href="">Join Now</a>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div> 
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the default padding and margin always start your code with :-

```
`*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}`
```